# ListView.ScrollIntoView on page opened

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have tried to call ListView.ScrollIntoView in Page constructor and in OnNavigatedTo (using Dispatcher to marshall the thread), but in both cases there was no effect. However, if I call it when user clicks AppBarButton, it works perfectly.

I have read that ListView builds its Visual model async and that that is cause of this, as the model is not built yet. However, I can't find proposed event in Windows Store version of ListView to subscribe to. I have tried to call ScrollIntoView with a timer in different intervals, but it all failed.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried ListView.Loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `ListView.ContainerContentChanging` event.

```
    void lv_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        YourItem item = args.Item as YourItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item == TheItemYouWant)
            {
                ListView lv = sender as ListView;
                lv.ScrollIntoView(args.Item);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't like adding timers but this will work as a last resort.

```
    private void ListViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lv = sender as ListView;
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        dt.Tick += (o, o1) =>
        {
            dt.Stop();
            lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.Items[50]);

        };
        dt.Start();
    }
```

Comment: That first worked, I changed it a little bit (I think there is no need to cast to specific item type, you would compare if objects are the same anyway).

Comment: And just to note, to avoid crashes, Dispatcher is needed when accessing ListView.